# Recursive nested initializer list taking variant

Tags: c++, nested, c++17, initializer-list, braced-init-list

I want an object `obj` to be initialized from an `initializer_list` of pairs. However, the second value of the pair is a variant of bool, int and again the `obj`. gcc reports trouble finding the right constructors I guess. Can I make this work recursively for the following code?

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

struct obj;

using val = std::variant<int, bool, obj>;

struct obj
{
    obj(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, val>> init) {
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    obj O = { {"level1_1", true }, { "level1_2", 1 }, { {"level2_1", 2}, {"level2_2", true}}};
}
```

gcc 12.1 doesn't get it:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:57:93: error: could not convert '{{"level1_1", true}, {"level1_2", 1}, {{"level2_1", 2}, {"level2_2", true}}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'obj'
   57 |     obj O = { {"level1_1", true }, { "level1_2", 1 }, { {"level2_1", 2}, {"level2_2", true}}};
      |                                                                                             ^
      |                                                                                             |
      |
```

Any hints on what I need to change?

**EDIT**: It seems that the approach using initializer lists is probably not suitable. Maybe there exists a solution using templates which is also appreciated. I know it is possible from [nlohmanns json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) (see section "JSON as first-class data type"). Also the solution should get by without using heap allocations during the initialization process.

Comment: `{ {"level2_1", 2}, {"level2_2", true}}` doesn't look like a suitable initializer for `std::pair<std::string, val>`. Where's the `std::string` component?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's true, I changed that. However it doesn't work even with `obj O = { {"level1_1", true }, { "level1_2", 1 }, { "level1_obj", {{"level2_1", 2}, {"level2_2", true}} } };`

Comment: You probably need to be explicit about the nested initializer, as in `obj O = { {"level1_1", true }, { "level1_2", 1 }, { "level1_obj", obj{{"level2_1", 2}, {"level2_2", true}} } };` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9od3WhxvE)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! But is there any way (maybe a wrapper?) to avoid that requirement? I'm currently trying to make sense of this source: https://www.foonathan.net/2022/05/recursive-variant-box/ but I want to stack allocate it and not throw it on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igor noted, without any changes to your type or constructor, your code can compile fine with an explicit type specified for your subobject:

```cpp
obj O = { 
  { "level1_1", true },
  { "level1_2", 1    },
  { "level2",  obj {
      { "level2_1", 2    },
      { "level2_2", true },
    }
  },
};
```

I believe the problem may originate with the particular combination of `std::pair`, along with a variant that contains an incomplete type. We can observe this by replacing `std::pair<...>` with our own custom type that lacks any internal storage:

```cpp
struct obj
{
  using mapped_type = std::variant<int, bool, obj>;

  struct kv_pair
  {
    kv_pair(const std::string &k, int  v) { }
    kv_pair(const std::string &k, bool v) { }
    kv_pair(const std::string &k, const obj &v) { }
  };
  
  obj(std::initializer_list<kv_pair> entries) { }
};

int main(void)
{
  obj _ = {
    { "level1_1", true },
    { "level1_2", 1    },
    { "level2", {
        { "level2_1", 2     },
        { "level2_2", false },
      },
    },
  };
  return 0;
}
```

With this, we get your desired syntax, but lack any implementation. My guess here is that the problem lies with `std::pair` in combination with `std::variant`. We can get back our storage by having `kv_pair` instead be a convenience wrapper over pairs of strings and pointers, i.e.

```cpp
struct kv_pair : public std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<mapped_type>>
{
  kv_pair(const std::string &k, int        v) : pair(k, std::make_shared<mapped_type>(v) { }
  kv_pair(const std::string &k, bool       v) : pair(k, std::make_shared<mapped_type>(v) { }
  kv_pair(const std::string &k, const obj &v) : pair(k, std::make_shared<mapped_type>(v) { }
};
```

So for a full and complete implementation:

```cpp
struct obj
{
  using mapped_type = std::variant<int, bool, obj>;

  struct kv_pair : public std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<mapped_type>>
  {
    kv_pair(const std::string &k, int        v) : pair(k, std::make_shared<mapped_type>(v)) { }
    kv_pair(const std::string &k, bool       v) : pair(k, std::make_shared<mapped_type>(v)) { }
    kv_pair(const std::string &k, const obj &v) : pair(k, std::make_shared<mapped_type>(v)) { }
  };

  obj(std::initializer_list<kv_pair> entries) 
  {
    for (auto &[k, v]: entries)
    {
      _entries.emplace(k, *v); 
    }
  }

protected:
  std::map<std::string, mapped_type> _entries;
};

int main(void)
{
  obj _ = {
    { "level1_1", true },
    { "level1_2", 1    },
    { "level2", {
        { "level2_1", 2     },
        { "level2_2", false },
      },
    },
  };
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a further note, you requested that this be constructible without heap allocations, but this is simply not possible when you have a self-referential data type. Presumably your `obj` type will contain a map of strings to other `obj` values, so necessarily having a subobject in your initializer list already implies some amount of allocation. There's possibly a way to get your syntax without an explicit heap allocation for primitives, i.e. by allocating the `obj` instances only, i.e. by having `kv_pair` be a subtype of `std::pair<std::string, std::variant<int, bool, std::shared_ptr<obj>>>`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It's unfortunate that the compiler doesn't seem able to derive the types in the first place, but heap allocs are a no go so I have to stick with the declarative method mentioned first.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the restriction of no heap-alloc? My guess is you're after a structure reminiscent of `struct data { map<string, variant<..., data>> }` which, since you have `data` possibly containing another `data` object of unrestricted depth, would require a heap allocation internally to function. Or is the restriction simply that the initializer should never allocate?

Comment: The restriction is simply that the initializer should never allocate. This is because I'm on an embedded system which can use different heap allocation schemes, one of which is no heap allocations :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use template metaprogramming to create specific types at compile time.

```cpp
template <int Level>
struct obj {
    using value =
        std::initializer_list<
            std::pair<
                std::string_view,
                std::variant<bool, int, typename obj<Level-1>::value>>>;
};

template <>
struct obj<1> {
    using value
        = std::initializer_list<
            std::pair<
                std::string_view,
                std::variant<bool, int>>>;
};

int main() {
    obj<2>::value o{
        { "level1_1", true },  // (string, bool)
        { "level1_2", 1 },  // (string, int)
        { "level2", obj<1>::value{  // (string, obj)
                { "level2_1", 2 },
                { "level2_2", true }}}};
}
```

In the code above, `obj<2>::value` would be compiled to:

```cpp
std::initializer_list<  // obj<2>::value
    std::pair<
        std::string_view,
        std::variant<
            bool,
            int,
            std::initializer_list<  // obj<1>::value
                std::pair<
                    std::string_view,
                    std::variant<bool, int>>>>>>
```

I believe no heap allocations should be made, since you are only making use of basic types (bool, int), `std::string_view`, `std::pair` and `std::variant` (should behave like a struct), and `std:initializer_list`. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/j9a9en3Kv) for a demo showing all the `o` values in the example above are on the stack.